# MySQL Casting in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, casting, odbc, datareader

Okay, so I'm attempting to print out the contents of a table in a comma-separated file.

```
using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM pie_data WHERE Pie_ID = ?", con)) {
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Request.Form["pie_id"]);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
        string finalstring = "";
        while (reader.Read()) {
            finalstring = reader.GetString(9) + ",";
            for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i = i + 1) {
                finalstring = finalstring + reader.GetString(i) + ",";
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Write(finalstring);
    noredirect = 1;
}
```

My table layout is:

```
CREATE TABLE `rent_data` (
`Pies` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Name` VARCHAR(85) NOT NULL,
`Email` VARCHAR(85) NOT NULL,
`Pie_Rent` DATE NOT NULL,
`Rent_To` DATE NOT NULL,
`Returned_Date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Place` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`Purpose` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
`Comments` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
`Pie_ID` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
INDEX `Pie_ID` (`Equipment_ID`)
)
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'.
```

On the line:

```
finalstring = finalstring + reader.GetString(i) + ",";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.getstring.aspx), conversions are done by the ODBC driver, and if they're not supported, GetString doesn't convert to string. Since you have non-string columns, you're facing this problem.

Instead of GetString, use [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.getvalue), and then convert to string using ToString():

```
finalstring += reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ",";
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you are using `GetString()` to get an Int64. You should use `.GetInt64` instead for that particular value

you should also call `IsDBNull` to look for null values before calling this method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods

Answer (score 0):

`GetString` tries to cast the column value to string. This won't work with non-literal columns and you apparently have them in your table (`Pies` is of type `long`, `Pie_Rent` is a `DateTime`) etc. You have to use other method of extracting the data like for example:

```
  finalstring = finalstring + reader[i].ToString() + ",";
```